# readfile or fpassthru from begin to byte number

Tags: php, readfile

So `readfile`/`fpassthru` is great for efficiently sending either a full file (`readfile`) or a file from a particular seek position till FEOF (`fpassthru`).

Are there any such efficiency methods aside from `fread` that I can use if I wanted to stream arbitrary positions or from the beginning to an arbitrary position in the file?
(ie. `fpassthru($fp, begin, end)`)

Comment: Because I have an idea, what you are trying to achieve: Have a look at `mod_xsendfile` (there are solutions for other webservers than apache as well, for example `X-Accel` for nginx). Streaming files trough PHP is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Hey KingCrunch, the reason I need this is that I need to do some analytics while the file is being sent (ie. byte 0-1000, do something, 1000-2000, do something, 2000- FEOF).

From my understanding of xsendfile, its a fire and forget where I can't execute code in while the file is being streamed.

Comment: Yes, it is (and thats the advantage ;)). Don't know, what "do something" is, but maybe it's better to do it "outside" (for example using a cronjob)?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're *actually* trying to accomplish?  See [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).